# Actionlistener won't let me access an array

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a 2d dbl array filled with data, which i can call anywhere within the code:

```
System.out.println(twodarray[0][0]);
```

and it works just fine. When i call it as part of Actionlistener it won't work, and i get a Null pointer exception.

My event listener code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)      
 {
     if (e.getSource() == firstbutton)
     {

         System.out.println(twodarray[0][0]);

     }

 }
```

I'm at a loss as to where to start fixing this. The array exists with valid data as shown by the println's anywhere else in my code. Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: should you give us slightly more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the array; that's not the problem. The problem is that the the array variable is null when the action listener is called. Be sure that you're not shadowing the array variable inside of a constructor or method. For a more detailed answer, please provide more detail regarding your problem and your code.

In other words are you initializing the *class array variable*, or are you only initializing an array variable that is local to a method or constructor?

Comment: Bingo, so obvious once you see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to keep in mind that the listener is running on the UI Thread. Make sure that your not populating your 2d array someplace else.